# How to use delete function for a class object?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

This program is a student Database with add and delete functions for both students and courses. I have an issue successfully deleting a specific student from the database. Also, when I attempt to add more than one student to the database with a new student ID,it states that the student is already in the database when they aren't supposed to be. I've attached code snippets of the object class and the add and remove functions for the student. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Cheers .

```
class student {
public:
    int studentid;
    course * head;
    student (int id){ studentid = id; head = nullptr;}
    student () {head = nullptr;}
};

void add_student(student DB[], int &num_students)
{ 
    int ID;
    cout << "Please enter the id of the student you wish to enter " << endl;
    cin >> ID;
    for(int x = 0; x <num_students; x++)
    { 
        if (DB[x].studentid == ID);
    {  
    cout << "the student is already in the Database" << endl; return; } }
    student numberone(ID);
    DB[num_students] = numberone;
    num_students++; 
}

void remove_student(student DB[], int &num_students)
{ 
    int ID;
    cout << "Enter the student id you wish to delete from the Database " << endl;
    cin >> ID;
    // This is where I have the error
    // student * pointer2 = student(ID);
    //   delete pointer2; 
}
```

Comment: That isn't a linked list. `delete` has no business being in this code. You need to consider the location where the student was in the `DB` array as a "hole", then compact the remainder of the array from that point forward down by one slot to fill that hole.

Comment: You need to read up on linked lists. You don't seem to know what a linked list is. You claim that your Database is made up of linked lists, but your code contains no trace of it.

Comment: I realize that the part of the code with the linked lists was associated with the "courses" linked to the students and other courses. I apologize for not realizing that before, I just had trouble removing a student from the Database. I didn't include that part of the code because it wasn't associated with the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use 'delete' operator, unless you use the 'new' operator to create an object

```
student * pointer2 = student(ID); //wrong 
delete pointer2;
```

1st option is

```
 student pointer2(ID) //no need to use delete operator here
```

In this option '.'operator is used for accessing class members. Example

```
pointer2.studentId
```

2nd Option

'delete' operator is used to deallocate the memory that allocated using 'new' operator

```
student * pointer2 = new student(ID);
delete pointer2;
```

here '->' operator is used for accessing class members. Example

```
pointer2->studentId
```